# Cannot connect to server using DNS Name

Tags: linux, windows, windows-7, samba, windows-10

So yesterday one of our main servers decided to break and stop working.
We reverted to a backup and had some network issues that turned out to be because the ethernet connections had changed to eth2 and eth3 instead of the original eth0 and eth1.

I resolved this and everything seemed fine until a user tried to access the server using its DNS name. They tried using \servername\share (samba share)
Connecting via IP Address works fine (\server IP\share)

If I ping the server by DNS name or IP address, I get responses straight away.

I tried using Windows Diagnostics on it to see if it could shed some light on the issue and it came back and said:
"The remote device or resource won't accept the connection" (See below link)
[Windows troubleshooter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xaCk.png)

The server we are connecting to is SuSe Linux 10 and we are connecting to it from Windows 7 Pro & Windows 10 Pro machines.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the session token on your workstations with

`net session \\samba.ip.address /delete`

and restart the workstation service.

There is also a session file on the Samba server, usually in the config directory, which may have to be recreated because of the hardware change (I'm being vague about this as it's been a while and I don't have a Samba server to hand). This should be a case of stopping the server, deleting the file and restarting it.

Comment: Tried that but still cannot connect unfortunately

Comment: Do you have access to the logs on the server? They might give you an idea.